# Preventing app's attempt to alter calculated field value

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq, entity

This is a bit complicated…
I have a SQL table `TABLE_A`. This table has 3 columns `Qty` , `Price` and `TotalPrice`. To ensure consistency, `TotalPrice`  is a calculated field at database level `Qty` * `Ptice` = `TotalPrice`.
On the `WinForms` interface side I use `Generic collections` like `List<Table_A>`to prep the collection before committing it to the database. I feed `List<Table_A>` into `DataGridView` for user’s review before committing. Now the problem is the calculated field. To display the value of calculated field before committing, I have to assign value to `TotalPrice` on the interface side. Works good when inserting new records because value gets ignored and database calculates its value. However, when I load table values into `List<Table_A.`, change record’s `TotalPrice` (by changing `Qty` or `Price`) and try to update database I get `A member that is computed or generated by the database cannot be changed.` exception. How can I work around it so the app would not try to submit change to calculated field?
I use LINQ and Entity Framework objects to connect to SQL database.

Comment: There is probably an easier method, but you can add an instead of trigger (assuming SQL Server) and do the right update on the database side.

Comment: On your C# class change TotalPrice to have the DataAnnotation NotMapped. Then change your TotalPrice to only have a getter that returns Qty * Price.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to sleep on it. I went back to my original concept of using `DataGridViewCellFormatting` event and applied math there. Removed code altering calculated field within interface and it worked as intended. Now I get complete representation of data in review, before inserting or updating, without calling the database.